# PHP Dynamic URL Parameters and GET

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'd like to ask if it's possible to use a dynamic url and GET at the same time.

Let's say my current dynamic url is: 
`https://yourdomain.com/blog/this-is-a-title`

Would it be possible to make this work too:
 `https://yourdomain.com/blog/this-is-a-title?action=delete`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

The dynamic url mentioned first works fine, but I want to make the second work as well. 
This is my **.htaccess** - hope it helps.

PS: I know that the regex in my htaccess isn't correct, it's just an example.

Comment: So you want to hit url `https://yourdomain.com/blog/this-is-a-title` in browser and change it in browser to `https://yourdomain.com/blog/this-is-a-title?action=delete` please confirm once?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 no. I want to display the blog at `https://yourdomain.com/blog/this-is-a-title` but if it has the parameter `?action=delete` I want the user to see a different page (but it's still on the same page) - Let me know if you still didn't understand!

Comment: Let me re-confirm that we are on same page or not. You want URL `https://yourdomain.com/blog/this-is-a-title?action=delete` to be served by index.php is this right? If yes then what parameters it should pass to index.php file? eg: `index.php?delete`?

Comment: We're always on the same page - page doesn't change! 
**index.php** : https://yourdomain.com/blog/this-is-a-title
**index.php?action=delete** : https://yourdomain.com/blog/this-is-a-title?action=delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your .htaccess Rules file in following manner. Please make sure that your htaccess Rules file is present in root folder(where blog and htaccess both are residing in it; htaccess shiouldn't be inside blog folder; should be place same folder with it). Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Newly added rules here...
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/(?:[^?]*)?action=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?action=%1 [L]

##Old Rules OP's htaccess ones.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```